# Redraw does not happen properly when repositioning the "Close Reason" pop-up

Tags: bug

To recreate this, begin to close a question by clicking on the question's "close" option.  When the "Why should this question be closed" pop-up appears hover over the pop-up title and click and drag the pop-up.  The page does not refresh properly.  This is happening in Firefox 43.0.1. I have not tried verifying this behavior in other browsers.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Edit: It works properly in Chrome on the same computer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, in either Chrome or Firefox 43.0.1. Can you take a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Does it still happen after you restart Firefox? Does it still happen after you restart your machine? I guess this is Firefox on Windows: which version of Windows?

Comment: Yes, it still happens after restarting Firefox.  This on Windows 7 SP 1.